# What is the difference of these forms?

Tags: sentence-construction, collocations

I have seen many forms of these forms and confused about them. Do they have a same meaning? When we should use a specific form?

1. “oil production”  “the oil production” and “the production of oil” and “production of oil”
2. “Synthesis of protective metabolites” and “the synthesis of protective metabolites”
3. “ion detoxifying” and “detoxification of ions” and “the detoxification of ions”
4. “drug effects on” and “effects of drug on”

Answer (score 1):

Whether to use **oil production** versus **production of oil depends on context** and what is being written about. They mean the same thing.

However, for example, in a **CHART heading**, you'd use: Oil Production [in Iran or Saudi Arabia or Mexico].

In a paper or news article, you **might** write: the production of oil in Iran has increased in the last few years.

But there really is no reason to write it in long form unless you are going to **characterize the oil**:

The production of **oil for industrial uses** has a long history in the region. In that example, you wouldn't write: Oil production for industrial uses. I hope that is clear.

Now, the x of y is used for general statements: **The** production **of** oil for industrial uses is quite expensive.

However, you can also write: **Production of oil for industrial uses is quite expensive** for a general statement, as well. It's really a stylistic choice most of the time. If you really are emphasizing oil production in a specific place, you might write: The oil production process in Mexico has been difficult. It then refers to that specific one and not somewhere else.

**The synthesis of protective metabolites** works like the oil thing. However, you can also see: **Protective metabolite synthesis** is a long process. It becomes an adjective.

Drug effects is not usually seen:

The effect of [x drug] on patients has been beneficial. Generally, just **drug effects alone** is slightly unusual. We would write: the effects of drugs on teenagers is difficult to measure.

**The effects of drugs on x is not the same as the oil and metabolite thing.** Drugs' effects is generally best avoided. As that would be a **most unusual possessive** **whereas with the  oil and metabolite examples the nouns are being made into adjectives** (adjuncts).